# Match the string with a regexp to get substrings between '='?

Tags: javascript, regex

The sample string is `=aa=bb=cc=dd=`.

I tried

```
string.match(/=(\w*)=/)
```

but that returns only `aa`.

How do I find `aa`, `bb`, `cc` and `dd` from the sample string?

Comment: Note that you could also simply split the string :)

Comment: @WoLpH, how would it be possible to split the string without either an extra **=** in each item or an empty item starting or finishing the array?

Comment: @DanielGimenez - it would, but you could very easily skip values that were blank when processing the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex will match explicitly your requirements, and put the non, delimiter portion it the first capture group:

```
=([^=]+)(?==)
```

Unfortunately JavaScript regex does not have look behinds, otherwise this could be done in much easier fashion.

Here is some code:

```
var str = '=([^=]+)(?==)';

var re = /=([^=]+)(?==)/g,
    ary = [],
    match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    ary.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(ary);
```

Comment: What is the `(?==)` capturing group for? Without it, it works fine too. Can you please post a string where this is important?

Comment: @learner, without the look ahead, then `nomatch` in `=a=b=nomatch,=c=` would match.  Just trying to be as exact as possible.

Comment: @learner What Daniel means is that `(?= ... )` is a lookahead. It checks that the character coming just after is what is within the `...` without consuming it, so that you don't get alternate results (i.e. aa, cc and missing bb, dd).

Answer (score 2):

`var values = yourString.split('=');` You'll get an array with all your required values.

Comment: Deleting an answer to rid yourself of the downvotes and then reposting a corrected answer is strongly discouraged. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141924/191410) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38469/191410)

Comment: Because my answer just had to be corrected a little bit, and now it's correct. I don't think that the correct answer should have downvotes :)

Comment: So I make a little mistake, and others start to downvote and laugh at me in the comments instead of helping me to correct it. A very kind society I'd say :)

Comment: A little teasing - it's not personal. Please consider, though, that the purpose of this site is not to hold your hand, but to provide high quality answers for the rest of the world. Posting incorrect or misleading answers is anathema to that mission and is going to be met with the appropriate response - downvotes and comments pointing out the error. You've corrected your mistake and provided a decent answer, which is more than most newcomers would do. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `/[^=]+/g` should suit your needs: [have a try](http://regexr.com?35gde)!

Answer (score 1):

## Description

this regex will capture all the non-equal characters in your string

`=([^=]*)(?==)`

[image]

## Example

Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/vPW2GJqBWP

**Sample Text**

```
=aa=bb=cc=dd=
```

**Matches**

Capture group 1 will have the following

```
[0] => aa
[1] => bb
[2] => cc
[3] => dd
```

Comment: Why did this get down voted?  It is the correct regex.  Though now it is pretty much the same answer I gave...

Comment: @DanielGimenez I didn't vote it down, but I think it's the fact that without a loop, the regex will not work properly (and the loop was added later, after which one vote was reversed).

Comment: people are playing games artificially inflating their answers by downvoting others

Comment: You should test your code instead of posting JavaScript guessing how it should work; this doesn't work

Comment: @Denomales: you forgot the global flag (and I got down voted too).

Comment: Yes, I got downvoted also. Gintas K's answer is the only one without a downvote...

Comment: @Doorknob - sp00m doesn't have any downvotes either. Maybe they are in cah00ts?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 That's because he answered later

Comment: @Doorknob - I am aware of that. Gintas' original post had 2 or 3 downvotes before he deleted/reposted. Perhaps the perp simply didn't notice the new, unspoilt answer.

Comment: It was more then one user. Oh well, just another day on StackOverFlow.

Comment: @Denomales - You are still missing the [global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags). Your example is in ruby, not javascript. This answer will not work in javascript without the global flag.

Answer (score 1):

Just use simply:

```
string.split('=')
```